# Restrict pull from Git

Tags: git

Lets say in Git, I have two branches - "BranchA" and "BranchB". "BranchA" is where everyone can see and work on it (pull/push etc.) but for "BranchB", only few people with access can see the branch and work on it and the rest cannot. How do I achieve this?

Under branch_protection_rules/new in Git, I could only find to lock branches to user cannot push. But I want no pull nor push.

Comment: That's not something that _git_ (by itself) can provide in terms of restricting access on a single repo.... you might have a **separate** repo where only certain people can work on. You might be able to pull it off with service providers but I am not going to elaborate on what each provides.

Comment: "Branch protection rules" have nothing to do with Git; that's a feature of **GitHub**.

Answer (score 2):

As @larsks pointed out, the branch permissions are a function of GitHub, not `git`. You could stick to GitHub functionality to add a layer of protection to your process.

- Fork the current repo in GitHub.
- Restrict who can access the forked repo.
- Have the isolated branch work done on the forked repo.

This will keep all that code out of the eyes of other devs who can only access the parent repo. This also restricts pull requests and code reviews to whoever can access the forked repo.

Finally, once the code is ready for production, you can merge it to the forked repo's `main` branch, then create a PR to push it up to the parent repo. But of course, everyone can see the new code once it's there.